# Composite C1 pages cannot be saved

Tags: content-management-system, c1-cms

I am having problems saving pages in Composite C1. It worked fine for a long while and I don't recall installing anything new in Composite. Now when I click save and publish on a page on which I've made changes often it will pop up with a message saying "Save Resource? - 'pagename' has been modified. Save changes?" I click yes but the save and publish button keeps being active. It doesn't save my changes. It seems that 1 out of 10 times or something I can save, but most times it fails. Could this be a problem with my hosting? If so, what could that be? Can I see a log somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This sounds more fit on Server Fault however

Comment: @BenAnderson you can see the log file in the top menu in the console "Tools | Server Log". You have to be logged in as administrator to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the tabs contain a field that needs a value. If you open up that tab, you should see one of the fields have a 'value missing' alert, marked with red. Try tabbing through tabs to see if this is the case.

It is a bug in Composite v3.2 that the tab(s) containing fields with validation errors (like 'missing value') isn't visually highlighted. Normally a red alert icon shows up on the tab when you press save, and hints you to go open up this tab.