# Composite C1 pages cannot be saved on hosted site

Tags: c1-cms

I asked a question earlier that was closed because it was too vague: [Composite C1 pages cannot be saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028959/composite-c1-pages-cannot-be-saved)

I have more info about the problem now:
I am having problems saving pages in Composite C1. It worked fine for a long while. Now when I click save and publish on a page on which I've made changes often it will pop up with a message saying "Save Resource? - 'pagename' has been modified. Save changes?" I click yes but the save and publish button keeps being active. It doesn't save my changes.

I cannot reproduce the error locally running i Visual Studio, but when I log in to the admin panel on my hosted site I experience the problem a lot. The log in C1 doesn't show any errors and there's no fields in the page that are giving validation errors.

Can I change a setting in the web.config or somewhere else in order to turn on more extensive loggint or in order to turn up a timeout when saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else coming across this issue, here's a blog post (Aug 31) from the authors (with a patch!):

[Composite Saving Issue - Patch](http://community.composite.net/Blog/2012/08/31/Patch-available-fixing-NET-45-issues)

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to .net 4.5. I recently installed 4.5 and I had multiple websites stop saving. If you have recently installed .net 4.5 you might try uninstalling it, or hope they release a fix for it soon.

edit: I can confirm that .net 4.5 was my issue, after uninstalling it, all my Composite C1 sites are saving again!

Comment: I too can confirm that this is a .net 4.5 issue with Composite C1 - we did test with pre-releases of 4.5, but the RTM do give this problem. We are looking into it.